# Maven project that doesn't create a jar

Tags: java, maven

I want to make a Maven meta-project; it won't contain any code, just a pom.xml. The purpose of the project is to have a place where I can declare some dependencies, and then use this project as a dependency somewhere else. How can I tell Maven not to generate a jar file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

`<packaging>pom</packaging>`?

Answer (score 2):

Set the packaging to `pom`

```
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.example.group</groupId>
   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
```